# Sonar View retrieve data without using the HTTP protocol

Tags: sonarqube

I am working with Sonar3.7.3.
I use the commercial Views plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/
This plugin connected to the remote Sonar with the protocol HTTP

Is there a way to retrieve data from a remote View Sonar without using the HTTP protocol (Export / import data from remote sonar database...) ?

in fact I have two sonar which are on different network and this two sonar can't communicate with the HTTP protocol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's relative to a commercial product where the support is external to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the commercial Views plugin, then please contact the SonarSource commercial support mailing list.